Standard error and confidence intervals
About theoretical concepts... We use confidence intervals to do an inference to extrapolate results from study to similar sample. Is this true?
Which is the difference between a confidence interval, and dividing the result by  $\sqrt{n}$, how does the standard error occur?

This question has been asked many times on CV. Please take a bit of time to study previous answers. For example: Prediction Interval , Confidence Interval , Standard error, Error bars on bar graphs: Is reporting confidence intervals really better than reporting standard errors of the means?.

We use confidence intervals to estimate where the true parameter of a point estimate might be. Technically, the confidence interval has a certain coverage, e.g. 95% Think that asymptotically in 95% of the cases you compute a confidence interval, the true value is in this estimated interval).
The standard error (with this division by sqrt(N)) arises from looking at the sample distribution of the mean value and computing the standard deviation of this mean estimator.
